# SQL Server stored procedure executes fine from Mgmt Studio but not from website

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I actually have 2 problems. The "Update O" from below executes fine from SQL Server Management Studio (2005) but doesn't run when executed from the website (C#/ASP.NET). The only difference I made from the original working code was adding the LEFT command to LEFT(EmployeeBirthdate, 4)

This is strange because the first query runs fine when ran through the website, but the 2nd one just doesn't.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateTransfers]
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE p
    SET DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Transfer'
    FROM abc as p
    WHERE DATAREVISIONTYPE  = 'Delete' AND
    (SELECT COUNT([OriginalUserId]) FROM abc WHERE DataRevisionType = 'Add' AND FirstName = p.FirstName 
    AND LastName = p.LastName AND EmployeeEmailAddress = p.EmployeeEmailAddress AND EmployeeBirthdate = LEFT(p.EmployeeBirthdate, 4))> 0

    UPDATE O
    SET DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Modify' FROM abc as O
    WHERE DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Add' AND
    (SELECT COUNT([OriginalUserId]) FROM abc WHERE DataRevisionType = 'Transfer' AND FirstName = O.FirstName 
    AND LastName = O.LastName AND EmployeeEmailAddress = O.EmployeeEmailAddress AND LEFT(EmployeeBirthdate, 4) = O.EmployeeBirthdate)> 0
END
```

My 2nd problem is that when I add more sets to the set command they are not actually changing any data.

```
UPDATE O
SET DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Modify' 
    O.OriginalUserID = OriginalUserID, 
    O.EmployeeBirthdate = EmployeeBirthdate, 
    O.User_ID = User_ID
FROM abc as O
WHERE DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Add' AND
(SELECT COUNT([OriginalUserId]) FROM abc WHERE DataRevisionType = 'Transfer' AND FirstName = O.FirstName 
AND LastName = O.LastName AND EmployeeEmailAddress = O.EmployeeEmailAddress AND LEFT(EmployeeBirthdate, 4) = O.EmployeeBirthdate)> 0
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The commas behind the 'Modify' were from a poor job copy pasting. That was unfortunately not the problem.

EDIT 2: Also, when I execute the specific queries individually, the second one takes about a minute to complete, and the first is instaneous. On the other hand, if I highlight the entire stored procedure and hit execute, it finishes instantaneously, and has the same problem as if it was ran from the website. IE, the correct records are set to 'Transfer' but the 'Modify' does NOT work

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Your second query looks to be getting/setting values to the same value, i.e. O.OrginalUserID and OriginalUserID are one and the same in that context.

Comment: Also is there really a comma after `'Modify'`? That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @KevinDahl Do you have a recommendation on how to structure the query so that the O.OriginalUserID (etc) would work correctly like in the  "SELECT COUNT"?

Comment: @RBarryYoung There is no error message, the website(and a SELECT query) shows the changes made from the first query ('Transfer') but the second query didn't actually change any fields to 'Modify'

Comment: What is the DataType of the `EmployeeBirthdate` column and what are you trying to do with the `EmployeeBirthdate = LEFT(p.EmployeeBirthdate, 4)` comparison?

Comment: @RBarryYoung DataType = [EmployeeBirthdate] [nvarchar](250)
The idea is that (not by my choosing) The FirstName + EmployeeBirthdate is used as the unique identifier. Since there are numerous duplicates, letters were added to the end of birthdate (A,B,C) to differentiate. I use the LEFT because the birthdate is in mmdd format (with possible A,B,C afterward) and this this takes care of the problem that matches were getting skipped because even though the record was a match it had a letter after it.

Comment: What is "xxxx" format for a date/time string?

Comment: mmdd and it may have a single letter after it example: 0506C ...an explanation is, existing users are getting added to the list in different business units as new users, but they are actually the same person. The point of this stored procedure is to check if they are just a 'Transfer' instead of an actual new person and if they are the same person, they need to have OriginalUserID, 
    EmployeeBirthdate, 
    User_ID all edited to include the character (whether A,B,C,etc) at the end.

Comment: @Ryan you could structure the query so that the portion of the WHERE clause (which is where I assume you are wanting to get the other SET values from) is in the FROM clause as a subquery. You'd have to GROUP BY all of those values you wish to come from the subquery though, and use a HAVING clause for the count > 0. Your birthdate would likely still give you issues though, as you'd have to aggregate on the LEFT, but it still looks like you're wanting to set it to the full value.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma before "FROM:"

```
UPDATE O
SET DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Modify', FROM abc as O
```

Comment: The commas behind the 'Modify' were from a poor job copy pasting. That was unfortunately not the problem.